# How to send syslog over TCP in syslog server

Tags: syslog

I am sending syslog on UDP to remotehost its working fine but while i am sending log on tcp then logs are not routing to remote host.
I am using syslog server on FreeBSD8.3

can anybody tell me how to send logs to remote host on TCP using syslog server.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One issue I just ran into while trying to send log messages to an rsyslog server listening on tcp port 10514 was that it requires a last byte of 0A or line feed. I discovered this tcpdumping net cat as that was working but a socket connection was not. For ex the following will not work (the 155 is for local3 + err level)  :

```
import socket

syslogSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
syslogSocket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 10514))  
syslogSocket.send('<155>TEST FROM PYTOHON\000')
syslogSocket.close()
```

But this will work:

```
import socket

syslogSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
syslogSocket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 10514))  
syslogSocket.send('<155>TEST FROM PYTOHON\n')
syslogSocket.close()
```

To get the 155 check out a page like:
http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/412/syslog-sending-log-from-remote-servers-to-syslog-daemon/

Since PRI = (facility << 3) + severity 
And local3 facility == 19
And severity err = 3

```
PRI = (19<<3) + 3
        152 + 3
        155
```